# Is Team System a solution?

Tags: .net, asp.net, system

I am working on a web portal in ASP.NET (VS2008) with my 2 friends. We want to code, debug, test our webportal on different machines simultaneously.

How it can be done?
Is VS2008 Team System a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

To code, test and debug on any number of machines simultaneously you would need a respective number of copies of Visual Studio, regardless of the version.

What you're definitely need is some kind of source code control system. It can be MS-based, like Team Foundation Server, or something older like SourceSafe (known as being very buggy) or any other system. [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org)has many clients ([TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org), for example) that can integrate with Windows Shell. You can consider a third party plugin like [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) that will integrate with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think in the case of 2 machines only Team System will be a good idea, especially with the overhead and required software and licensing, the better solution in my opinion is using SVN on a server machine with Apache server & tortoise SVN client on the dev boxes which is a Shell extension to Windows Explorer and very robust and can be accessed in a small network or externally, and you can even host your code on Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Just be sure you use HTTPS/SSL over the Internet:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395265.aspx